# why postsharp log level can only be changed once

Tags: postsharp

we are using the following codes in app_start to change log level dynamically by retrieving the log level from `web.config`.

```
LoggingServices.GetSource(LoggingRoles.Tracing).SetLevel(LogLevel.Debug));
```

after build, we change the log level to `Error`, we don't see debug level information anymore, but if we change it back to `Debug`, we still don't see the debug level information. If we set initial level to be `Error`, after rebuild, we don't any debug info, then change level to `Debug`, we see debug information, then we change it to `Error`, we still see debug information. the change of log level only work once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only cause I can see is that you have the `AllowDynamicEnabling` property set to `false` in your logging profile. See http://doc.postsharp.net/log-enabling#optimizing.

In other cases, you should be able to change the verbosity dynamically. We fixed a bug related to this a couple of months ago, so make sure you have a recent version.